# rsync with scandics on filenames

Tags: backup, rsync

I am trying to create multiple scripts for mirroring peoples homefolders to external hard drives, and everything other is going well, except when foldername or filename  include scandics.

For example on my test:

```
rsync /home/halmiset/Videot/äktk/ -vr .
```

[image]

Comment: Does this option help: `--iconv=utf8` ?

Comment: Are there any symlinks that don't work?